# CKEditor : How to bring the button controls "to the back"

Tags: html, css, ckeditor

Is there a way to bring the button controls in CKEditor so that the search results of my user list can appear at front?

I apologize for images that contains code.

**1. Default Control Image**
[image]

**2. After Dropdown of Users**
[image]

**3. Code Snippet of the Memo Textbox (incl. controls):**

```
<tr class="inputValues">
    <td>
        <text for="MemoValue" style="font-size:14px; width: 15%">Note: </text>
    </td>
    <td>
        <textarea style="border:1px solid #D8D7D6;border-radius: 3px; width:101%; margin-bottom: 5px; padding-left:5px;" rows="3" id="MemoValue"></textarea>
    </td>
</tr>
```

**4. Whole Memo Textbox class**
[image]

**5. Memo Control Button class**
[image]

**6. User Control List class**
[image]